# How to deal with library mismatches in 3rd party android libraries?

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, android-facebook

I'm writing an android app that uses both ActionBarSherlock and the Facebook Android SDK. Both these libraries provide android-support-v4.jar in their libs folder:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/libs/android-support-v4.jar
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/libs/android-support-v4.jar

However, in the head revision both versions of the support jar are different. This causes builds of my app using eclipse to fail.

I'm using both libraries by including them in the repo of my app as git submodules. One solution would be to fork one of these libraries, update the version of android-support-v4.jar in the fork, and point my submodule to the fork. While perhaps this is the right way to go, somehow this feels wrong.

I wanted to know if there were other alternatives before I use the above method. A number of popular Android libraries seem to use maven, is using maven a good solution for solving this problem, and a good idea for android apps in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all Delete android-support-v4.jar from All(yourProject,FacebookSDK etc. ).

Then follow below steps:

Right Click on Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library and The again Right Click on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties do same on Facebook SDK and Other Libraries.

and Clean-Build all your projects(Facebook SDK,your Project and Libraries).You are Done.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since I'm using git submodules, deleting android-support-v4.jar will require me to fork these libraries. Are there other solutions that don't require me to fork these libraries?

Comment: as you click Add Support Library it will againg add the android-support-v4.jar in both your project and libraries you use.please check.it will not fork your libraries.

Comment: I agree those steps will probably get it to build on my machine, but all other devs that use my repo will have to follow the same steps, as will any new devs. It would be preferable to be able to build from just a simple git recursive checkout. But I realize I may be being stubborn. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: as you will do it there is no need to do it again for those who uses your repo.just give it a try.

Comment: Marking as accepted, this is the solution that I went with, but note that if you are using git submodules of 3rd party projects, all other users will have to perform this step unless you make a fork of those projects. Thus I still haven't tried a solution I'm happy with. Still wondering if it's maven, but switching my project to maven may be days of work.